# Making Mathjax dynamic so it renders input without page refresh

Tags: plugins, plugin-mathjax

I use the [Simple Mathjax plugin](https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/) on my Wordpress site to allow users to add nicely formatted mathematics by writing it within dollar signs, `$...$` or `$$...$$`.

This works on pages and in posts but not in chat windows.

After reading much documentation and searching for answers to my issue, I found out that the MathJax script is run at `onload` of the page itself. So, after page refresh. Then all `$...$`  `$$...$$` occurrences are formatted nicely.

But I need the MathJax rendered **dynamically**, so it will appear nicely formatted when posted as a message in a chat *without* requiring a page refresh.

[image]

Basically, I need the functionality which [in made in this link](https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic-2.html).

As far as I can see in the [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/typeset.html), there is a `Typeset` command that should make dynamic math formatting possible with a line like:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

But I am not sure how to input this into the Wordpress plugin. **Any advice on this?**

I use the BuddyBoss theme and platform for my Wordpress site. If it is of any help, here is the Simple MathJax settings page:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The mathjax plugin uses the JS library, just use the JS library at runtime rather than using the WP plugin